# Подскажите, как получить название последней запушенной кем-либо ветки в git?

Tags: git

Для улучшения понимания вопроса приведу следующее определение HEAD:

> "HEAD – это указатель на текущую ветку, которая, в свою очередь, является указателем на последний коммит, сделанный в этой ветке."

а нету ли указателя с такой интерпретацией?:

> "указатель на ветку, которая, в свою очередь, является указателем на последний коммит, сделанный в gitlab"?

Как командами git-а можно получить название ветки/ID последнего коммита?

Использовал git show --name-status, но эта команда показывает информацию по последнему коммиту в ветку git, в которой нахожусь.

Ещё новичок в git, но я стараюсь. Помогите, пожалуйста, с вопросом.

Comment: Вы хотите странного и несуществующего. В гит нет понятия последнего коммита «вообще».

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git log --all -n 1 --pretty=%H
```

> abcdef01234567890abcdef01234567890abcdef

```
git branch --list -r --points-at abcdef01234567890abcdef01234567890abcdef
```

> origin/feature/12345

Comment: Благодарю! Близко, очень, но пока ещё что-то не то. Тестирую в одиночку данную схему, делаю коммиты. Возможно ошибаюсь, делая изменения в ветках непосредственно на gitlab, принимая это за полноценный пуш и комит. Можно же принимать такие изменения за полноценные коммиты (в графе отображается как пуш с удалённого клиента)?

Comment: @Vic, я не знаю.

Comment: сработало! Сперва прописываем git pull, а потом уже эти две команды. Спасибо!!

Comment: @Vic, тогду уж fetch, а не pull?

Comment: я, кажется, понял. Вообще цель моего мероприятия перейти в эту последнюю запушенную ветку. Поэтому сперва делаю `git fetch`, (не pull, чтобы не возникало локальных конфликтов мержа) потом получаю ID и  имя ветки, потом через `git chekout <branch>` перехожу на эту ветку и уже там делаю `git pull origin <branch>` для этой ветки. Всё верно!?

Comment: @Vic, вроде бы pull лишний, если ветки до этого не было. Но если была, то да.